# "Has" or "Have" with "Each"?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

This is from a multiple choice question with 4 options, but I narrowed it down to 2:

> Select the best version of the following sentence: 
>   (there is really no sentence after this, just the answer choices)
>
> - a) Each of the conference rooms **has** a computer display.
> - d) Each of the conference rooms **have** computer displays.

In my eyes these choices are both perfectly fine, I can't see anything wrong with either of them.

Comment: Look carefully - given the way you asked the question I think this is something you know: should the verb agree in number with the subject or with the object? (This type of question is more suited for our sister site: [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)), but I think this particular one is a matter of mere oversight.

Comment: @Lucky I guess it has to agree with the subject, so I think the correct answer is d?

Comment: Half right - I think that we should take this to ELL if you don't mind :-). I've asked the moderators to do it.

Comment: Each is singular, so you would say each of the rooms **has** a computer display.

Comment: Remember that _each_ is equivalent to _each one_, which is more obviously singular. The conference rooms are not the subject: _each_ is.

Comment: @Lucky: I was initially inclined to agree, but apparently this is from Daniel Defoe, 1748 [*...as this is a Point in which both Cities are very tenacious, I will distinguish the Particulars wherein each of them have the Advantage over the other*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22+this+is+a+point+in+which+both+Cities+are+very+tenacious%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I'm not saying Defoe is the last word in English grammar, but I think there's more here than a simple stumbling block for learners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mildly interesting: I followed your link, and in the first result [it is actually "has."](http://imgur.com/hQMiYYM)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is the 1801 edit.  [The original](https://books.google.com/books?id=NSgJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22+this+is+a+point+in+which+both+Cities+are+very+tenacious%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mP1TVfCJLMWSNsC-gOAH&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%20this%20is%20a%20point%20in%20which%20both%20Cities%20are%20very%20tenacious%22&f=false) is as you quoted.

Comment: @Lumberjack: It's not just "original" and "revised". I see there's three or more in just those four matches - the "original" and some "copies" have the stylistically ungainly (to my eye) ***indeed*** as the fifth word in the sentence. And one copy has ***we** will distinguish the particulars...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question has started an interesting debate, so point taken - it might belong to ELU after all (and I owe @ Ovi an apology - my intention was just to get you answers and prevent downvotes :-)). I've had a quick look at Google Books and was very surprised to see that "each of them have" gave more than 10^6 results, and "each of them are" twice as much - verbs in singular gave more, but still a million hits is a lot even if some are false positive or come from unreliable publications. I still think that the grammar book wants **"a"** as the correct answer, though :-).

Comment: @Lumberjack: Hmm. Well, apart from *our* comments here, all I see is that someone downvoted my attempt to address the issue below. I can't for the life of me imagine *why*, but I guess we'll just have to give it time to see if anyone else has a more positive/forthcoming contribution to make.

Comment: Check out the info in your nearest usage dictionary, such as *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage".

Comment: Here's a related excerpt from my *MWCDEU*, page 286, for entry "each", for the ***"each of X"*** issue: "It seems likely that notional agreement is the decisive force in most of these examples, singular and plural. If you are thinking of *each* as individualizing, you will use the singular verb; if you think of it as collecting, you will use the plural. Both singular and plural are standard, but singular is much  more common."

Comment: @F.E.: That accords with my own feeling. Obviously singular is *much* more common, and in most contexts it's the only acceptable form. But the Defoe example doesn't seem inherently invalid - certainly not by the standards of the time, and not necessarily even today (I just feel that particular one is a bit "dated", but perhaps I'm influenced by other elements within the text).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: The rule is ***each*** is always singular (apart from contrived contexts). But lots of learners and even some native speakers can be thrown by *each of the [plural noun]*, and treat it as plural.

---

From [grammar.ccc.commnet](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm)...

> **Each** is often followed by a prepositional phrase ending in a plural word (**Each of the cars**), *thus confusing the verb choice.* [italics mine]

I expect most people would simply take it for granted that *each* is always singular, regardless of whether it happens to be just one word in the construction *each of the [plural noun]*, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each%20of%20them%20have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceach%20of%20them%20have%3B%2Cc0) is interesting (it suggests the usage was much more common a couple of centuries ago).

And let's not forget indisputably valid usages such as *We each of us have our faults*. It takes some doing to figure out exactly why the presence of the apparently optional ***we*** there precludes us from continuing with the equally valid (as a complete sentence) *Each of us **has his** faults* (I'm guessing it's because the actual subject is plural ***we*** and that ***each*** is an adjective in an adjectival modifier, but what do I know?).